# App Not installing while running npm start -> npm run android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, node.js, react-native

info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

not installing app

Answer (score 0):

**on android folder cmd run**

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

**and run**

```
./gradlew clean
```

**and root project run**

```
react-native run-android
```